# Does the Facebook login app have to be the same for the android and website?

Tags: android, facebook, debugging, facebook-login, release

I am have created a app and website where I both have implemented Facebook login. My website login works fine but my app login does not. I'm not sure what the problem is. It worked fine with the debug version. This is what it shows me [image: App login error showing when selecting facebook login]

What I have done so far:

1. I have one facebook app for both android and the website. (I had two separate ones before)
2. I added the release key hash to the facebook app. So I have two key hashes in my facebook app now, debug and release hash. I have tried replacing the debug key hash with the release one after I published it to the app store and just use that one, but that also didn't work. So I added both.

Please help!

Comment: You definitely want to use the same Facebook app for both. If you've put the hash shown in that error into your app's settings and it's still not working, I'd a) give it an hour or two in case the data isn't updated immediately and b) file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/.

Comment: Ok I have both in the same Facebook app now. I've added that hash from the error to my app and I'll give it some time. I'll keep you updated if it works.

Comment: It still does not work! Any suggestions?